# Видео не по центру

Tags: c#, aforge

Я использую библиотеку aforge,при подключении к видео-устройству,видео транслируемое в videosourceplayer показывается не по центру,почему так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по изображению Вы используете готовый пример [Snapshot Maker](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html).
Значит допустить ошибки, во время написания кода, Вы не могли. Поэтому проблема, скорей всего, скрывается в самом видео-устройстве.

Если Вы самостоятельно писали код, тогда выложите минимальный рабочий участок кода в котором наблюдается данный эффект. Я чуток поигрался с примером, с ходу(если специально не пытаться) подобного эффекта я не добился.

Comment: Да,я использовал готовый пример,подозреваю что дело в драйверах.